# Adding Authorization Role to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-update, authorization, roles

I want to be able as an Admin to add Authorization Role to other users..when I click the Add Role button it says that it added the role to that user..but when I check in the Rails Console the role of that user is still nil.

```
def index
    @user = User.new
    @users = User.all
end

def update
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user][:username])
    if @user && params[:user][:role] == "editor"
        @user.role = "editor"
        @user.save
        flash.notice = "Added role 'editor' to #{@user.username}."
        redirect_to "/adminsettings"
    elsif @user && params[:user][:role] == "admin"
        @user.role = "editor"
        @user.save
        flash.notice = "Added role 'editor' to #{@user.username}."
        redirect_to "/adminsettings"
    elsif @user && params[:user][:role] != "editor"
        flash.notice = "Please chose 'editor' if you want to add this role to this user."
        redirect_to "/adminsettings"
    else
        redirect_to "/adminsettings"
        flash.notice = "Please choose one of the users below."
    end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for @user ,:url => {:controller => "admin_settings", :action => "update"}, method: :patch do |user| %>
    <%= user.text_field :username, :placeholder => "Username" %><br />
    <%= user.text_field :role, :placeholder => "Role" %><br />
    <%= user.submit "Add Role" %>
<% end %>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <strong><%= user.username %></strong><br />
<% end %>
```

Routes

```
  get '/adminsettings', to: 'admin_settings#index'
  patch '/adminsettings', to: 'admin_settings#update'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your use of calling params to this...

```
def update
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if @user && params[:role] == "editor"
        @user.role = "editor"
        @user.save
        flash.notice = "Added role 'editor' to #{@user.username}."
        redirect_to "/adminsettings"
    elsif @user && params[:role] == "admin"
        @user.role = "editor"
        @user.save
        flash.notice = "Added role 'editor' to #{@user.username}."
        redirect_to "/adminsettings"
    elsif @user && params[:role] != "editor"
        flash.notice = "Please chose 'editor' if you want to add this role to this user."
        redirect_to "/adminsettings"
    else
        redirect_to "/adminsettings"
        flash.notice = "Please choose one of the users below."
    end
end
```